# How do I create a linear regression model in Weka without training?

Tags: linear-regression, weka

Suppose the linear model I want is `sales = (0.4 * age) + (0.05 * income)`. How do I create this linear regression model in Weka without training on any data? I just want to save a model file that contains the linear relationship that I already know. No training is necessary. Is this possible in the Weka GUI or through the Java API? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The Weka classifier `MathExpressionClassifier` that comes with the [ADAMS framework](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/), allows you to do that. You only have to supply the formula after the `=` as the expression.

Another alternative, if you don't want to switch to ADAMS, is the [mxexpression-weka-package](https://github.com/fracpete/mxexpression-weka-package) library. However, you will need to convert the attribute names in your formula to `attX` (with `X` being the 1-based attribute index). This package is also part of ADAMS.